# Nodeclipse Debugging Won't Stop at Breakpoints

Tags: node.js, nodeclipse

I'm trying to debug a test Node app with Nodeclipse in Eclipse.  I am following the directions under "debugging" from the Nodeclipse home [page](http://www.nodeclipse.org/).   I set a breakpoint via the ruler, right click the file, and select debug as Node Application.  Eclipse switches to the Debug perspective, and then pauses the debugger on the first line of my file (which did not have a breakpoint), which is now showing in a new editor with a filename like "C_workspace_project_app.js" and with my code wrapped in a function like:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
```

If I hit "F8" to continue the program, it does not stop at the breakpoint I have set in the original editor.  However, if I add breakpoints in the new editor, the program will pause on them.  This would be fine, except there is no way to set breakpoints in other files.  Seems to me the breakpoints I set in the Eclipse editor are not being synced with the debugger.  I do see an error abotu breakpoint toggling in my .metadata/.log file, attached.  Am I doing something wrong?

I have Eclipse 4.2.2, with many plugins installed, like the Web Tools Platform, JSDT, etc.  I have Nodeclipse 0.4.0, and ChromeDevTools 0.3.9.

.metadata/.log:

```
!SESSION 2013-06-14 09:44:05.682 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20130204-1200
java.version=1.7.0_15
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2013-06-14 09:44:11.343
!MESSAGE Unable to find Action Set: org.eclipse.rse.core.search.searchActionSet

!ENTRY org.eclipse.debug.ui 4 120 2013-06-14 09:44:15.343
!MESSAGE org.eclipse.debug.ui.toggleBreakpointsTargetFactory extension failed to load breakpoint toggle target because the specified id is already registered.  Specified ID is: org.chromium.debug.ui.ChromiumToggleBreakpointTargetFactory

!ENTRY org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui 4 0 2013-06-14 09:44:16.315
!MESSAGE Could not load repository template extension contributed by org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.ide with connectorKind bugzilla

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 2 2013-06-14 09:44:49.957
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.UnreportableException: The resource is inaccessible: /STANDALONE_V8.
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.utility.FileUtility.getResourcePath(FileUtility.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.utility.SVNUtility.getSVNInfoForNotConnected(SVNUtility.java:884)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.SVNFolderListener$1$1.visit(SVNFolderListener.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.SVNFolderListener$1.run(SVNFolderListener.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.SVNFolderListener.resourceChanged(SVNFolderListener.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager$1.run(NotificationManager.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.broadcastChanges(NotificationManager.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.broadcastBuildEvent(Workspace.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

!ENTRY org.chromium.debug.core 1 0 2013-06-14 09:46:22.804
!MESSAGE SDK:org.chromium.sdk.internal.transport.SocketConnection: Shutdown requested
!STACK 0
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.chromium.sdk.internal.transport.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:88)
    at org.chromium.sdk.internal.transport.Message.fromBufferedReader(Message.java:134)
    at org.chromium.sdk.internal.transport.SocketConnection$ReaderThread.run(SocketConnection.java:166)
```

Comment: Synchronization of breakpoints between Nodeclipse Editor and ChromeDevTools Editor is what have been added in 0.2. Can you share your code snippet?

Comment: Could you try to install Nodeclipse into a fresh eclipse install and try with a new clean workspace?

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  I'm new to Stack Overflow and didn't have email notifications configured.  I ended up starting from scratch with the [Node Tools Suite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nodeclipse/?source=dlp) and debugging is working so far.  I got some null pointer errors while the minimap was open, but closing it fixed that.

If either of you want to post an answer suggesting a clean install, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install Nodeclipse into a new fresh eclipse install and run with a new clean workspace, it should work well.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, that did work for me.  I'm not sure which other plugin I had that was causing a problem.  If I figure it out I'll let you know.

Answer (score 2):

Your project folder needs to be inside the Eclipse workspace folder. (not referencing to a project in another location)